# bouncing animation for image

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to animate an image like bouncing.I am able to bounce it forward but I am not able to push it back.
I am using this code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
hair.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Please help me out ..I am struct at this point and not able to solve this problem.Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Use these few line of code to get animate an image like bouncing.

```
 imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);

 //imgView is your UIImageView where you set an image 

[self.view addSubview:imgView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.5 animations:^{
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
        imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;                            
    }];
}];
}];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please note that from [UIView reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> Use of this method is discouraged in iPhone OS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods instead.

So in your case you might want to implement something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^(void) {
    hair.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^(void) {
            hair.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
        }];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, you just need to call one of them, and they will call each other automatically

-(void)animateZoomOut
{

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^ {
                     self.imgGift.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self animateGiftZoomIn];
                 }];
```

}
-(void)animateZoomIn
{

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^ {
                     self.imgGift.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self animateGiftZoomOut];
                 }];
```

}